# Does deleting an key from Object creates/returns new Object?

Tags: javascript, object, object-reference

I need to delete an property/key from one object comparing the other as in the below example

```
    var Obj1 ={
        a : '1',
        b : '2',
        c : '3',
        d : '4'
    }

    var Obj2 ={
        a : '1',
        b : '2',
        d : '5'
    }

     for (const key in Obj1) {
        if (!Obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            delete Obj1[key];
        }
    }
```

I have two objects `Obj1` and `Obj2`. Need to compare two Objects and remove the missing key in `Obj1`. that is I am removing key `c` from `Obj1`.

It is working as expected.
What I am wondering is whether new Object reference is created for this Obj1 after deleting or the Object reference is same?

How to find that?

Comment: *Modifying* an object (as `delete` does, or a "normal" property assignment will) does *not* create a new object..

Comment: ... Why would `Obj1` suddenly be a new reference? Think of what issues that would give. Think of _one_ good reason why that should happen... A bit of critical thinking will make the answer quite obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object reference is the same, you're merely modifying it (as a commenter says).

Deleting object properties changes the underlaying class that the VM generated. If this object is on the hot path, it has significant performance implications. The object *shape* (e.g. described [here](https://v8project.blogspot.de/2017/08/fast-properties.html)) is different, so the JIT compiler has to create a new class and ditch the old one and mess with the referrences. But aside for performance implications, it's not changing anything in our (js developers') world.